# Append an Auto-Incremented number to the end of a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, makefile

When I run this script I would like to count the number of files in a sub-directory outlined in `save_path` and add that number to the new file being created.

For example:

If `C:/xampp/htdocs/add/text/` has **1** file which is named `Text0.php`, then the next time this script runs it should create a new file named `Text1.php`.

This is my code so far:

```
import os.path

save_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/add/text/'
name_of_file = 'Text'
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".php")

file1 = open(completeName, 'w')
file1.write('it worked')
file1.close()
```

This script creates the file `Text.php` and saves it to `C:/xampp/htdocs/add/text/Text.php`.

I'm looking to find how many files are already in `C:/xampp/htdocs/add/text/` and then add that number to the next file created like this:
`Text + 'file_count' + '.php'`

```
logic:
if sub-directory has 1 file:
Text1.php
if sub-directory has 2 files:
Text2.php 
if sub-directory has 3 file:
Text3.php
if sub-directory has 4 files:
Text4.php
```

Comment: What prevents you from using a loop?

Comment: I think you're probably right, i'm just not sure how to apply an on going loop to a file creation script. Can you please give an example?

Comment: First find how many files are there using os.popen("ls -t file*.txt") this will give u list of files['file3.txt','file2.txt','file1.txt','file.txt']. Then iterate over list and rename every file name using mv command (file3.txt -> file4.txt, file2.txt -> file3.txt, file1.txt -> file2.txt, and file.txt -> file1.txt) then add your content in file.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers that others have put forwards helped me to create a program that every time the .py file is called it counts the number of files in the sub-directory and adds it to a file name and creates the file

The Code I Used:

```
 path, dirs, files = next(os.walk("C:/xampp/htdocs/addfiles/text/"))
 file_count = len(files)
 save_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/addfiles/text/'
 name_of_file = 'text'
 completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file + str(file_count) + ".php")
```

after running this 3 times i got:

```
['text0.php', 'text1.php', 'text2.php'] in the .../text directory
```

if you want to create 'text1.php' first, instead of 'text0.php' then make a change to file_count

```
file_count = len(files) + 1
```

after running this three times you'll get:

```
['text1.php', 'text2.php', 'text3.php']
```

i also found writing to this newly created file is really easy later in my code i add

```
page = 'content you want to add to this file'
file1 = open(completeName, 'w+')
csv_writer = csv.writer(file1)
csv_writer.writerow(page)
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be best to do this in some sort of loop. You are trying to increment the value, create the name of the file based off that value and the original name, and then use that and the path to create a file. Based off your code it could look something like this.

```
for i in range(10):
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+str(i)+".txt") 
    file1 = open(completeName, 'w+')
    toFile = 'it worked'
    file1.write(toFile)
    file1.close()
```

Comment: Generally Don't use fixed Length to Solve any problem.. in this case take dynamic range from path where these files are placed

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "take dynamic range from path where these files are placed" could you elaborate?

Comment: Here dynamic range means.. find how many files are already present in path ( use some thing like: ls file*.txt ) then iterate your loop according to that

Comment: would (for i in range(10)) count up +1 at a time or would it pick a random int in the range of (10)?